# How to retrieve delayed stock price by python via IB TWS

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, ibpy

This is the code attempting to retrieve AAPL delayed stock price via Interactive Broker (IB) TWS.

However, none of data is retrieved.

As you can see, app.reqMarketDataType(3) has been called to set delayed data. (3 is delay)

I've logged into demo account in IB TWS and ensured "Enable ActiveX and Socket client" is selected.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

import threading
import time
   
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType == 2 and reqId == 1:
            print('The current ask price is: ', price)

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

#Create contract object
apple_contract = Contract()
apple_contract.symbol = 'AAPL'
apple_contract.secType = 'STK'
apple_contract.exchange = 'SMART'
apple_contract.currency = 'USD'

#Request Market Data
app.reqMarketDataType(3)
app.reqMktData(1, apple_contract, '', False, False, [])

time.sleep(10) #Sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data
app.disconnect()
```

Comment: Are you sure the demo acct has delayed data?  The code looks ok but I'll try and test it Monday.  Note that when the market is closed you should ask for delayed frozen data (4).

Comment: I've got this code running successfully, thank you - but it is failing after returning the market data:

'unhandled exception in EReader thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lb/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ibapi/reader.py", line 34, in run
    data = self.conn.recvMsg()
  File "/home/lb/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ibapi/connection.py", line 99, in recvMsg
    buf = self._recvAllMsg()
  File "/home/lb/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ibapi/connection.py", line 119, in _recvAllMsg
    buf = self.socket.recv(4096)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor'

Answer (score 1):

The code works ok.  The problem is you don't print unless you get tickType 2(real time ask), delayed ask is tickType 67.

https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/tick_types.html